# Not Redirecting header() . Not echoed anything

Tags: php, authentication, header

My Login system works fine in my Localhost, but not in Godaddy's server. It seems to be a problem with header() Function. But i haven't echoed anything before the header file

```
<?php
    {
        session_start();
        include_once 'db_connect.php';

        if (isset($_POST))
         {

            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $logpwd = $_POST['password'];

            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT password FROM members WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1");
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);


            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();

            // get variables from result.
            $stmt->bind_result($password);
            $stmt->fetch();


            // Check if a user has provided the correct password by comparing what they typed with our hash
            if (password_verify($logpwd, $password))
            {
                $sql = "SELECT * from members WHERE email LIKE '{$email}' LIMIT 1";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);
                $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                $_SESSION['user_check'] = 1;
                $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
                $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
                header('Location: ../index.php');
            }
             else {
                header('Location: ../login.php?error=cred');
            }
         }
    }

    ?>
```

Login form Given below

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="functions/fn_login.php">
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email / Mobile No." required name="email">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password" required name="password">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-3">
                  <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox"> Remember?
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
```

db_connect.php

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'usersystem');
?>
```

What might be the problem with my code. Am i doing it wrong.

Note : Both localhost and Godaddy have PHP version 5.5

Answer (score 0):

There could be some warning which is not produced on your localhost server, but gets printed on Godaddy's server thus blocking the `header()` function. You should check server's log files to see if there is any error logged.

If you're testing this in Chrome, you should press F12 to activate the debug console and then click Network tab, to see if your redirection is received by your browser.

Comment: Method : POST
Status Text : 500
Internal Server Error

any help?